# cd ripping software with error detection / correction

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ripping

Ive used CDEx on Windows in the past, but it requires 3rd party aspi drivers to be installed to function - which don't support USB DVD drives.

More recently i've been using Asunder on Ubuntu...

However CDEx used to notify about jitter errors which usually manifested as audio glitches (crackles and pops) in the output audio - as a result of read errors caused by scratches.

Asunder will retry on errors - but ultimately silently continue with bad data if the disk is too scratched to read properly.

So I'm looking for a replacement free cd ripping software that runs on Ubuntu or Windows, supports ripping from a USB hosted DVD/CD-ROM drive, and either performs some kind of error correction or at least flags the tracks with bad reads so I can avoid adding faulty tracks to my media center?

Answer (score 1):

Try  imaging it to the hard drive using ddrescue prior to ripping, it may help you with some damaged tracks.

Answer (score 0):

[cuetools](http://www.cuetools.net/wiki/Main_Page) - checks the cd with a handful of databases, including accurip. Once its done, check the logs, and if it matches, you know its perfect.

Also take a look at cdparanoia and EAC if the cd is REALLY damaged. If you need to rip multiple formats, DBPoweramp .[Hydrogen audio has a shiny table with a list of features of various rippers if you want other options](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Comparison_of_CD_rippers)